# What to call a relation/ship that is based on interest and benefit?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some relation/ships are based on care and responsibility, others are not but are based on benefits and interest. What this second kind is called.

It does not need to be an interpersonal relation; for example, it can be relation an organization has with a person.

It also does not need to be a mutual interest relationship. So A might start a relationship with a particular group because she see a benefit in such a relationship.

I prefer single words and I am already aware of such words as *benefit-based* or *interest-based*, I want other words with the same meaning.

Comment: Parasitic? Symbiotic? Beneficial? Convenient?

Comment: With people or pets, [cupboard love](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cupboard_love) may be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The adjective **remunerative** is defined:

> 1 financially rewarding; lucrative
>
> *highly remunerative activities*

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/remunerative)]

An example from [ASU](https://www.asu.edu/aad/manuals/policyarchives/ACD/Oct1998/acd510-01a.pdf):

> *notification of consulting or other remunerative arrangement*

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein to *mutualistic,* [***transactional***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transactional/transactional) may suit your purpose. It suggests a two-way exchange of benefits that may or may not be in balance.

> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> **1** Relating to the conducting of business, especially buying or selling.**^**
>
> **1.1** Relating to exchange or interaction between people.
>
> **^** One of the examples given for this sense is *‘a purely transactional relationship’.*

Comment: I agree that this matches what the OP wants, but a little extra explanation is needed. A transactional relationship is one which is usually thought of as _solely_ by an exchange of something. A does something for B, B does something for A. If the mutual benefit is gone then the friendship is no longer there. There is no sense of loyalty or altruism or emotional investment.

Comment: @Mitch While that's true, I understood that Sasan wanted to describe a relationship based not on "care and responsibility" but on "benefits and interest", i.e., not a friendship and perhaps entirely devoid of "loyalty or altruism or emotional investment".

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is "[Mutualism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mutualistic)" or "Mutualistic".

***noun***

> 1. A relationship between two species of organisms in which both benefit from the association.
> 2. The doctrine that the interdependence of social elements is the primary determinant of individual and social relations, especially the theory that common ownership of property, or collective effort and control governed by sentiments of brotherhood and mutual aid, will be beneficial to both the individual and society.
> 3. Sociology. the force or principle of [mutual aid](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mutual-aid).